# Direction of a moving sprite

Tags: java, math, direction

I'm doing a simple breakout game and I have some problem to understand how I should handle speed and direction of the ball to move it in different diagonal paths. I'm using this code in an update method:

```
xPos += xSpeed * direction;
yPos += ySpeed * direction;
```

If I use different vaules of `xSpeed = 2` and `YSpeed = 1` I can change to different diagonal paths, but I still want the same speed. If I increase value of `xSpeed = 4` to get another diagonal path, then the speed is also increased, and I want the ball to move in the same speed. For the value of `direction` I use 1 or -1. But I guess it would be better to change the value of `direction` to get diagonal paths in degrees? In a breakout game the ball has to bounce back in the oppesite direction. I'm not good in math, so I would preciate some help to solve this. Any ideas how I can improve my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `sine` and `cosine` functions to get the relative movement in `x` and `y` axis.

Like:

```
xPos += speed * Math.sin(movementAngle);
yPos += speed * Math.cos(movementAngle);
```

Using the above ([polar coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system)) in various animations has the advantage of ease in modyfing direction or velocity of movement (which are `speed` and `movementAngle` variables respectively). When using cartesian coordinates (`x` and `y` position), change in either velocity or direction of movement would require non-obvious changes to both `x` and `y`.

Formulas in the solution above are nothing more than conversion from polar to cartesian coordinates.

**Edit:** to get the more "natural" behaviour, when `movementAngle` of `0` means moving right, `PI/2` - up, `PI` - left and `3*PI/2` - right, use the following:

```
xPos += speed * Math.cos(-1*movementAngle);
yPos += speed * Math.sin(-1*movementAngle);
```

Comment: Is the movement angle in radians or degrees?

Comment: @3D-kreativ - in case of `Math.sin()` it's radians. [See the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sin(double)).

Comment: I guess it's working, I'm using this code: 
double angle = Math.toRadians(180);
xPos += speed * Math.sin(angle);
yPos += speed * Math.cos(angle);
I'm just a little bit confused, 180 degrees is up, I thought 90 degrees was up!? Do I use the same variable angle in both sin and cos?

Comment: @3D-kreativ - for 180 deg (PI), `sin(PI) = 0` and `cos(PI) = -1`, so `xPos` not changes and yPos decreases, thus the up movement. If you set angle to 90 deg (PI/2), you would get `sin(PI/2) = 1` and `cos(PI/2) = 0`) which would mean right direction. It's called the [polar coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates).

Comment: Hmmm, so there are both polar coordinates and cartesian coordinates then, I guess it's easier for me to understand the cartesian coordinates, so then I change the angle. When I studied math 0 degrees was to the right and counter clockwise 90 degrees up and then left 180...

Comment: @3D-kreativ - if you want the angle to match what you already know from math classes, you can always do the following (at the beginning): `angle = -1 * angle + PI/2`.

Comment: Usually, the cos of the angle gives you the x portion of movement, while the sin of the angle gives you the y portion of movement. This means that directions start at 0 degrees = east and turn counterclockwise, the convention for directions.

Comment: @Patashu, you're right, this would be maybe more clear when thinking in cartesian coordinates ;) I'll update the answer.